# GREP for a dynamic pattern in a file and print the other lines having former pattern and another pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, text-extraction

Lets say I have a log file which looks like this:

```
06/30/2015 00:17:20.716  INFO   06z07mjBYxFpzs Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723  INFO   06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.735  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.759  INFO   06z07mGDQ9thtY Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.755  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.827  INFO   06z07n2q9S4g07 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.855  INFO   06z07mxt44CF03 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.861  INFO   06z07n5mxfYkHg Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.873  INFO   06z07nm473brzB Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.902  INFO   06z07mM059k0tZ Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.970  INFO   06z07nx2lv9wzC Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974  INFO   06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.991  INFO   06z07ngwMW16zz Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994  INFO   06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.085  INFO   06z07n42C6Qczx Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07mxR42tZzw Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07mWbfVCGD3 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.095  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.123  INFO   06z07p0yBwLv0b Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.132  INFO   06z07nSLzf66Hk Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137  INFO   06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

What I wish to do is if:

- any line contains `"Matched Line"`, I need to get the unique id in column 4 (e.g. `06z07mjBYxFpzs`) and,
- search other lines having that unique id + the text `"Some Data xxyyzz"` and,
- print the line that has the matching patterns of (unique id + `"Some Data xxyyzz"`) on the console as final output.

So in this case the output should be:

```
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723  INFO   06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974  INFO   06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994  INFO   06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137  INFO   06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

The file I am talking here is a huge file (~200 GB file; having millions of records), on a shared server, so I **cannot** run scripts or commands that would take a lot of time.

**[EDIT]** - Currently doing through fgrep by printing the unique ids from `Matched Line` in one file and `Some Data xxyyzz` in other; but looking for a single line `grep`, `awk` or `sed` command (without having to create multiple files to `fgrep`)

**[EDIT 2]** - this output is not in a file, rather this is an intermediate output of a series of `grep` and `sort`.

**[EDIT 3]** - Updated Sample Input (not in order but jumbled):

```
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.716  INFO   06z07mjBYxFpzs Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.735  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.759  INFO   06z07mGDQ9thtY Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.755  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784  INFO   06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.827  INFO   06z07n2q9S4g07 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.855  INFO   06z07mxt44CF03 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.861  INFO   06z07n5mxfYkHg Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.873  INFO   06z07nm473brzB Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723  INFO   06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.902  INFO   06z07mM059k0tZ Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.970  INFO   06z07nx2lv9wzC Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974  INFO   06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.991  INFO   06z07ngwMW16zz Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.085  INFO   06z07n42C6Qczx Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07mxR42tZzw Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994  INFO   06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.094  INFO   06z07mWbfVCGD3 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.095  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100  INFO   06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.123  INFO   06z07p0yBwLv0b Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.132  INFO   06z07nSLzf66Hk Matched Line
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137  INFO   06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ordered Data

The following just goes through the file once and therefore should be fast:

```
$ awk '/Matched Line/{id=$4;next;} id==$4' file.log
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723 INFO 06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784 INFO 06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974 INFO 06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994 INFO 06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100 INFO 06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137 INFO 06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

In the sample input (original question), all the `Some Data` lines immediately follow their `Matched Line`.  This enables this fast and simple solution.

#### How to use in a pipeline

awk works well in pipelines.  If the input is not from a file but, as in **Edit 2**, from a pipeline, then use something like:

```
cmd1 <file.log | cmd2 | awk '/Matched Line/{id=$4;next;} id==$4' | cmd3
```

#### How it works

- `/Matched Line/{id=$4;next;}`

  Any time we find a line containing the text `Matched Line`, we save its ID in the variable `id`.  Since we do not want to print `Matched Line`, we tell awk to skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `id==$4`

  Any time that the current line has an ID (field 4) that matches our saved `id`, we print the line.

  (In awk terminology, `id==$4` is a condition: it evaluates to true or false.  When the condition is true, the action is performed.  In this case, we specified no action so awk performs the default action which is to print the line.)

#### Partially Ordered Data

In **Edit 3**, the data lines can appear at some random location after the matched line.  In that case:

```
$ awk '/Matched Line/{id[$4]=1;next;} id[$4]' file.log
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784 INFO 06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723 INFO 06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974 INFO 06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994 INFO 06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100 INFO 06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137 INFO 06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

Or, in a pipeline:

```
cmd1 file.log | awk '/Matched Line/{id[$4]=1;next;} id[$4]'
```

Comment: Great answer. Maybe this `awk '($5" "$6 == "Matched Line"){ id=$4; next } id == $4' logfile` could give you even more speed, it really depends on the original input.

Comment: @John1024 - Thanks for the simple command. What if the "Matched Line" and "Some Data" line are not in a particular order. Refer the updated input in question.

However, your answer is useful and encouraging me to learn awk!

Comment: @BadwolF From Edit 3, I see that the data lines never precede their corresponding matched lines.  That means that a fast single-pass approach can work.  I added a solution for that.

Comment: @John1024 - Awesome ... Thanks! Out of curiosity, what to do if the data lines do precede the matched lines or are in any random order.

Comment: @BadwolF Very good.  Because your file is so large, if a data line can precede a matched line by a significant amount, then we would need to read through the file twice, once to get the IDs and once to select the data lines.  This would, of course, slow it down and also it would make it difficult to use in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "Matched Line" data.txt  | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -l1 -i grep {} data.txt | grep -v "Matched Line"
```

1. Search for all "Matched Lines"
2. Print to stdout the 4th element in the line
3. For each line in the output run grep: search for the printed id
4. And search again but without "Matched Line"

Output:

```
06/30/2015 00:17:20.723 INFO 06z07mjBYxFpzs Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784 INFO 06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.784 INFO 06z07mdgC66vHc Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.974 INFO 06z07nx2lv9wzC Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:20.994 INFO 06z07ngwMW16zz Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100 INFO 06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.100 INFO 06z07nMgPJpPv1 Some Data xxyyzz
06/30/2015 00:17:21.137 INFO 06z07nSLzf66Hk Some Data xxyyzz
```

Alternatively, using bash's process substitution, we can reduce the number of times that the file `data.txt` has to be read to just two:

```
grep -f <(grep "Matched Line" data.txt  | awk '{print $4}') data.txt | grep -v "Matched Line"
```

Comment: If I understood the command correctly then its getting all the unique ids in an array and looping through that array on the entire file (n times if array has n values) to eliminate the lines that has "Matched Line" pattern for each value in array. 

If yes, then we already did that and that process was running for hours and sort of hung the server.

Comment: @Richard I added to your answer code that uses grep, as in your approach, but avoiding xargs so that the number of times that the file has to be read is reduced to just two.  It also has the side effect of eliminating the duplication of lines in the output.  (If you don't like the addition, feel free to revert.)

Comment: @John1024 .... that actually works fine, but still needs 2 pass of the complete file which takes a lot of time in our case where the file is huge. Actually we have been following this approach till now, and were looking for a single pass solution which was what you provided.